# jquery.mobile 1.4.3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: jquery, magento2.3.1

Whenever I trying to use a greater version of jquery 1.12.4 then this issue comes.
and whenever I use lower version then "post" function error

so please give me a solutions.

Comment: Show you code here.

Comment: please check this url  that code i am adding in 
 login.phtml https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281670/how-to-use-fb-getloginstatus-in-magento-2-3   so that errors comes

Comment: any update sir?